# Angular 2 failure to load resources

Tags: typescript, angular, systemjs

I am trying to use ag-grid in an angular2 app. I have followed angular2-quickstart tutorial and was successfully able to get the app running. After this for my project I am trying to get a grid for which I found this tutorial http://4dev.tech/2016/02/tutorial-angular-2-datatable-with-sorting-filtering-and-resizable-columns/. I followed the tutorial and there are some changes the way angular module is referenced here than in my code.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {AgGridNg2} from 'ag-grid-ng2/main';
```

and in the link above it has been mentioned as

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {AgGridNg2} from 'ag-grid-ng2/main';
```

I have my code in this git hub link https://github.com/svidya/ag-grid

I am having these errors

Uncaught TypeError: System.registerDynamic is not a function angular2-polyfill.js:1

http://localhost:3000/app/app.component Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

angular2.dev.js:136 Error: Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:3000/app/app.component
        at Zone.run (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular2-build/angular2.dev.js:136:17)
        at XMLHttpRequest.zoneBoundFn (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular2-build/angular2.dev.js:109:19)
    Error loading http://localhost:3000/app/app.component as "./app.component" from http://localhost:3000/app/main.js

Failed to load resource: http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic.js/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: In your repo, you have zone.js commented out, as well as a few other things. Have you tried matching your work to the Quickstart you are borrowing from?

Comment: yes I did follow quickstart tutorial at the first, which worked fine. Then I got stuck with ag-grid tutorial link I have posted in the above description. I was trying a couple of things when I did comment out zone.js.

Comment: I am a newbie to angular world and just following the angular quickstart  I did not understand a lot of things like zone.js , rxjs and polyfill .. why are they used ?

Comment: I was a newbie, too. A polyfill is basically a translator that enables you to use new features before they are supported (or use really old things that no one wants to support, ha!).


Here are some links that helped me to get a grasp on these additional libraries:

[LearnRx](http://reactivex.io/learnrx/)
[RxJs 5 Operators by Example](https://gist.github.com/btroncone/d6cf141d6f2c00dc6b35)
[Zones with Brian Ford - NG Conf 2014](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3IqtmUscE_U)

Comment: Sorry for the terrible formatting.